# Remove 1st item selection in MultiSimple selection listbox (Window Forms Application)

Tags: c#, listbox, selection, default

I have a listbox with selection mode of MultiSimple. In form_load, I have the code to get data source then select the default item I want from that list. This list contains all the tables in my database and I want to select the Users table as default item. However, the first table in the list is always highlighted along with the Users table. How do I avoid the first table is selected automatically as default?

Below is my code to populate my list

```
                var lwDBConn = Properties.Settings.Default.Target_DBConnectionString;                     List<string> tableNames = new List<string>();
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(lwDBConn))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    DataTable t = conn.GetSchema("Tables");
                    foreach (DataRow row in t.Rows)
                    {
                        tableNames.Add(row[2].ToString());
                    }
                    conn.Close();
                }
                tableNames.Sort();
                lstSQL.DataSource = tableNames;
                lstSQL.SetSelected(lstSQL.Items.IndexOf("Users"), true);
```

I have read other posts about avoiding 1st item being selected automatically but it doesn't fit into my situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right after you initialize the ListBox DataSource, you need to call listBox.ClearSelected.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the selection for only the first item you can call `lstSQL.SetSelected(0, false);`

Comment: This works too but ClearSelection is better choice for my case just in case for whatever reason other item was selected automatically and I didn't see it .